# SSRS Matrix with some Static and some dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a query that returns data like below from multiple databases. CoursesTaken is dynamic and can change with time with new courses added/removed.

```
 ====== ======= ============ ============= ======= ========= 
 Name      ID     Courses          Col1     Col2    Taken   
 ====== ======= ============ ============= ======= ========= 
 John      23    math                 x        y       yes  
 John      23    Chemistry        t            u       yes  
 Mary      40    math                  x       u       yes
```

====== ======= ============ ============= ======= =========

I want to pivot this on Courses so that it looks like below

```
Name  ID Math Chemistry Col1 Col 2 and so on
John  23 yes   yes
Mary  40 yes   no
```

I think for ssrs this can only be done from matrix so any changes to sql won't really help as courses are dynamic so how do I achieve the above?

EDIT
Dynamic pivot or any pivot outside ssrs matrix won't help as any pivot needs to be done from within ssrs.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a dynamic pivot in tsql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: I don't think any pivot outside ssrs would help as I don't know the numbers of columns which requires the use of matrix or atleast from what i know,

Comment: Yes, matrix and column groups.  Then columns outside the column group... that should all work out nicely.